# How can we remove x-forwarded-* header in Netflix Zuul filter?

Tags: proxy, netflix-zuul

I m building a simple PoC to strip-off the `X-FORWARDED-*` header while invoking microservice through Zuul gateway. I tried with `route` filter, but I couldnt find those headers there.

Where are the default headers are added and how can we remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Found out. Add the below in `application.properties`

> `zuul.add-proxy-headers=false`

Answer (score 0):

**Works for me**

```
RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getZuulRequestHeaders().remove("name of the header to be remove");
```

or

```
return new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
            private Set<String> headerNameSet;

            @Override
            public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
                if (headerNameSet == null) {
                    // first time this method is called, cache the wrapped request's header names:
                    headerNameSet = new HashSet<>();
                    Enumeration<String> wrappedHeaderNames = super.getHeaderNames();
                    while (wrappedHeaderNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                        String headerName = wrappedHeaderNames.nextElement();
                        if (!headerName.contains("x-forwarded")) {
                            headerNameSet.add(headerName);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return Collections.enumeration(headerNameSet);
            }

            @Override
            public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
                if (name.contains("x-forwarded")) {
                    return Collections.<String>emptyEnumeration();
                }
                return super.getHeaders(name);
            }

            @Override
            public String getHeader(String name) {
                if (name.contains("x-forwarded")) {
                    return null;
                }
                return super.getHeader(name);
            }
        };
```

**Simple one through the configuration file**

```
zuul:
    #mentioned header are ignored while build the request in zuul
    ignored-header: header_name1, header_name2
    #Will ignore all the x-forward-* headers
    add-proxy-headers: false
```